# Unwrap sphere with inverted normals

Tags: uv, normals, unreal-engine

Hello blender community!

I am trying to create a simple sky sphere (not a sky dome!) in blender, so that I can apply a material onto it later on in Unreal Engine 4. The export format is fbx, which works just fine with all the other models our team is using for the project.

My initial thought was to simply invert the normals of a sphere, unwrap it (seams marked orange) and export. However, no matter what material I apply to the sphere, as soon as I go inside the material creates weird distortions and horrible borders (refer to the red circles). I firmly belive that this is a problem with my bad unwrapping technique.

[image: Screenshot]

Can you tell me how to correctly unwrap the sphere?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Welcome to the site :). It's recommended to do a quick search before you ask a new question. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=unwrap%20sphere. Normals have next nothing to do with unwrapping in your case so that problem is unrelated.

Comment: Thank you @iKlsR for the quick response! I actually stumbled upon this and several other techniques throughout my research but I always believed that it is different for flipped normals. If I think about your statement tho, it makes sense and I feel a little embarrassed about my stupidity. I'll try the unwrap method described in your reference and come back to this post with my result. Regards